# Java - Shooting Towards Mouse Click

Tags: java

I'm trying to get my bullet to shoot towards the mouse click but it just shoots directly towards the left from the players position here's the code i used:

**Game Class (Main)**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener, MouseListener
{
    public Player player;
    private Image image;
    private Graphics graphics;

    public int MouseX;
    public int MouseY;

    private Font Title = new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD,20);
    private Font SubTitle = new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD,16);
    private Font Text = new Font("SansSerif",Font.PLAIN,11);


    public boolean playerUp = false;
    public boolean playerDown = false;
    public boolean playerLeft = false;
    public boolean playerRight = false;

     CopyOnWriteArrayList<Bullet> bullets = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();

     public static void main(String args[]){
        new Game();
    }

    public Game(){

        //Properties of JF
        setTitle("Ninjaa Fight!");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(697,670);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);   
        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //Properties of P
        player = new Player(150,520,90,90,100, "Images/Back S..jpg");
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){

        image = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphics = image.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(graphics);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        repaint();  
        g.drawRect(50, 50, 400, 570);
        g.setFont(Title);
        g.drawString("Ninjaa Fight!", 530, 70);
        g.setFont(SubTitle);
        g.drawString("Status", 530, 100);
        g.setFont(Text);
        g.drawString("Health: " + player.health, 530, 120);
        g.drawString("x Position: " + player.xPos, 530, 135);
        g.drawString("y Position: " + player.yPos, 530, 150);
        g.drawString("Enemies Total: " + "5", 530, 165);
        g.drawString("Enemies Defeated: " + "0", 530, 180);
        g.drawString("Enemies Left: " + "5", 530, 195);
        g.drawString("Level: " + "1", 530, 210);
        g.drawString("Player: " + "Guang Hu An", 530, 225);
        g.setFont(SubTitle);
        g.drawString("Instructions", 530, 255);
        g.setFont(Text);
        g.drawString("Up: W", 530, 275);
        g.drawString("Down: S", 530, 290);
        g.drawString("Left: A", 530, 305);
        g.drawString("Right: D", 530, 320);
        g.drawString("Shoot: L", 530, 335);
        g.drawString("Hit: K (Comming Soooon)", 530, 350);
        g.drawString("Switch Player: J (Comming Soon)", 530, 365);

        g.drawString("Credits: Areeb Raza - Designer, Coder and Programmer", 50, 640);
        g.drawString("Copyright © 2015 by Areeb Raza", 50, 655);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        player.draw(g);
        player.update(this);

        for(Bullet bullet : bullets){
            bullet.draw(g);
            bullet.update(this);
        }   


    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_W){
            playerUp = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_S){
            playerDown = true;
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_A){
            playerLeft = true; 
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_D){
            playerRight = true;
        }

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }


    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_W){
            playerUp = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_S){
            playerDown = false;
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_A){
            playerLeft = false; 
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_D){
            playerRight = false;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         Bullet playerBullet = new Bullet(-1, player.getxPos(),  player.getyPos(), 10, 10, "Images/Ninja Star.jpg");
            bullets.add(playerBullet); 

        MouseX = e.getX();
        MouseY = e.getY();
        System.out.println("(" + MouseX + ", " + MouseY + ")");

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**Bullet Class**

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Bullet extends GameObject {
    private int deltaY;
    public double xVelocity;
    public double yVelocity;
    public double angle;
    public Bullet (final int deltaY, final int xPos, final int yPos, final int width, final int height,  final String img) {
        this.deltaY = deltaY;
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.img = getImage(img);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        }


    public void draw(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(img, xPos, yPos, width, height, null);

        }


        void update(final Game g) {
            double bulletVelocity = 1.0; //however fast you want your bullet to travel
            //mouseX/Y = current x/y location of the mouse
            //originX/Y = x/y location of where the bullet is being shot from
             angle = Math.atan2(g.MouseX - g.player.getxPos(), g.MouseY - g.player.getyPos());
             xVelocity = (bulletVelocity) * Math.cos(angle);
             yVelocity = (bulletVelocity) * Math.sin(angle);
            xPos += xVelocity;
            xPos += yVelocity;

        }


    public int getDeltaY() {
        return deltaY;
    }

    public void setDeltaY(int deltaY) {
        this.deltaY = deltaY;
    }

    @Override
    Image getImage(String img) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(img);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a copy/paste bug here:

```
xPos += xVelocity;
xPos += yVelocity;
```

The last line should probably be

```
yPos += yVelocity;
```

Comment: Oh yeah i'll go fix that and tell you if it worked

Comment: nope not working